# Spark read CSV file using Data Frame and query from PostgreSQL DB

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark, I'm loading a huge CSV file using Data Frame code given below

```
Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").schema(customSchema)
                .option("delimiter", "|").option("header", true).load(inputDataPath);
```

Now after loading CSV data in data frame, now I want to iterate through each row and based on  some columns want to query from PostgreSQL DB (performing some geometry operation). Later want to merge some fields returned from DB with the data frame records. What's the best way to do it, consider huge amount of records.
Any help appreciated. I'm using Java.

Comment: Never iterate rows. Use a `join` to the other database.

Answer (score 0):

Like @mck also pointed out: the best way is to use join.
with spark you can read external jdbc table using the DataRame Api
for example

```
val props = Map(....)
spark.read.format("jdbc").options(props).load()
```

see the [DataFrameReader scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) for more options and which properties and values you need to set.

then use join to merge fields

Comment: Consider I can't join because of some geometry operation in PostgreSQL

Comment: sorry, Ii don't understand:
if you can do a query onto postgres then you can also use that query to get result set as a dataframe.
If you have to do geometry operations in the query, spark will push down that query to the postgresql db

Can you post an example of query?

Comment: I mean how we can join, we dont have any primary field to join, my requirement is  load data in data frame, then for each record I want to get some additional  information from PostgreSQL DB( consider some geometry operation like  ST_Distance) then combine additional data (distance between two geometry )from Postgres with data frame row.